# Errno::ENOENT: Error running rspec test, says file doesn't exist but it does

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec-rails

So I am trying to test for a controller but am running into problems. Part of the code requires a file to be loaded, but I am receiving this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory - ./public/licenses/58efcffc3d8441fcc0627164a8b1350aFCV5Hmashup_lic.xml
```

However, the file does exit. When I run it in the browser, it works just fine with no problems (but i still want to write a test).

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I am using a database when running the test. I know this isn't actually how I should do it, but I don't know any other way.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because your assumption about where the current working directory is when running the tests is wrong. try putting a `puts File.dirname('.')` in there to make sure you're running from the directory you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

As a debugging tool:

In your test, just before the statement that checks for the file, try adding

```
puts "list dir " + `ls ./public/licenses/`
```

to see if the file is really there.

Could be a permissions problem from the test user id

Could also be that the file isn't actually there...

Comment: Yeah, it did complain that it wasn't there again. However, when i ran the app, it work fine and did print out all the files in that directory? Why isn't it recognizing them when I run the rspec?